# Utilizing ng-include function properly

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have just started learning Angular.js (1 not 2) today and I was making several test codes to try to each function with reference from [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/angular/) and the other sites like that. I know this is not some trouble shooting forum but my code seems to return me an error that is not supposed to be there...

Error:

> angular.min.js:103 XMLHttpRequest cannot load partial/html/navbar.html. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.

from this piece of code i tried to make for myself...

```
<body style="padding-top: 70px">

    <div ng-app="">
        <div ng-include="'partial/html/navbar.html'"></div>
        <div ng-view></div>
    </div>

    <!-- Initialization -->
    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/angular-route.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

What am i doing wrong? even if i copy/paste codes, they seem to end up giving me the same result everytime

Comment: are you using a webserver to view your site ?

Comment: Do i have to? i mean its javascript..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure about the error message but maybe you are not using the correct path.

What's your app folder structure? If you have this one:

```
app --> views --> partial --> html --> navbar.html
```

then the path is:

```
<div ng-include="'views/partial/html/navbar.html'"></div>
```

Comment: it depends on, where the caller html page is located. If the `index.html` is in `app/html/` then you must write `../views/partial/html/navbar.html`

Comment: Exactly, in my case I have the index.html inside the folder app.

Comment: Thanks for the reply... i am sure about the directory because index.html is on the same folder as the partials folder.. making it partials/html/navbar.html

Comment: How are you running your app in the browser? Check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26711951/angular-js-routing-google-chrome-issue). It may help you

Comment: Did you fixed the problem? @DeathKing